# Assigning a global variable in a function

Tags: typescript

Hi I'm very new to typescript and javascript so my apologies if this is simple. 
If I console out filter while in the function it's correct but outside of that function it's not assigned. I know this is a scope problem I just don't know why or how it's solved.

```
var filter: string;

  input.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    const target: any = e.target;
    const filterString = target.value;
    filter = filterString;
    console.log(filter); // text from input block
  });
  console.log(filter); // nothing output
```

Comment: The keydown isn't called before you click on a button. Imagine all the code inside the eventListener is invisible, and its not a scope problem, its an asyncronous problem

Comment: How do you expect that to get a value before the user presses a key?

Comment: Ok thank you, This snippet was written by my professor in my webdev course so I took his word for it. That makes sense.

Comment: Ask your professor next time

Comment: This was part of a lecture, he didn't get it working in class so I've been trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
var filter: string;

  input.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    const target: any = e.target;
    const filterString = target.value;
    filter = filterString;
    console.log(filter); // text from input block
  });
  console.log(filter); // nothing output
```

`filter` is null when the code runs before the event `keydown` happens, so the log on the last line is actually working, it's outputting null.

Try logging the filter after the event has happened, have a look at [promise](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/promise.html)